Android kotlin SurfaceView error: disconnect: not connected (req=2)
This error is not a real problem, as the app still works as expected. I'm only curious. The app runs a background loop that calls delay(1000), then on the UI thread it draws on a SurfaceView. In this case, when I press the home button, my surface is destroyed and I get the following error:
2024-11-09 18:55:20.898 22258-22258 BufferQueueProducer     com.example.test                       E  [SurfaceView[com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity]#1(BLAST Consumer)1](id:56f200000001,api:0,p:-1,c:22258) disconnect: not connected (req=2)

If I comment out the delay, my surface is not destroyed and I don't get the error.
What is the reason of the error and how can I avoid it?
Thank you for your help.
This is a minimal reproduction activity:
package com.example.test

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.SurfaceHolder
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback
import android.view.SurfaceView
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    lateinit var surfaceView: SurfaceView
    var isAppRunning = false
    var hasSurface = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        surfaceView = SurfaceView(this)
        surfaceView.holder.addCallback(object : Callback {
            override fun surfaceCreated(p0: SurfaceHolder) {
                Log.d("tag", "On surface created")
                hasSurface = true
                runApp()
            }

            override fun surfaceChanged(p0: SurfaceHolder, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }

            override fun surfaceDestroyed(p0: SurfaceHolder) {
                Log.d("tag", "On surface destroyed")
                hasSurface = false
            }

        })

        setContent {
            AndroidView(factory = { context ->
                surfaceView
            })
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        isAppRunning = false
    }

    fun runApp() {
        isAppRunning = true
        val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        executor.execute {
            while (isAppRunning) {
                runBlocking {
                    launch {
                        // if delay is commented out, there is no error
                        delay(1000)
                    }
                }
                runOnUiThread {
                    if (hasSurface) {
                        val canvas = surfaceView.holder.lockCanvas()
                        canvas?.let {
                            surfaceView.holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

